# Arithmetic Summation in the file operations using Python Tkinter

Tags: python, math, tkinter, textbox, sum

please help me run arithmetic summation in the file operations using Python Tkinter

[input should be here (in the textbox)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jq4xR.jpg)

[summation output should be in TXT file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZE9U.jpg)

Source Code :

## INPUT

```
topup = tkinter.StringVar()

TextBox_1 = ttk.Entry(jendela, width=20, textvariable=topup)

TextBox_1.grid(column = 1, row = 3)
```

## BUTTON

```
def clickhere():

     f = open("TOPUP", "r")
     w = f.readline()
     f.close()
     f = open("TOPUP", 'r+')
     t=int(w)+ (topup.get())
     f.write(str(t))
     f.close()

button_ = ttk.Button(jendela, text='Top up!', command=lambda : clickhere, width=17)

button_.grid(column=2, row=3)
```

Comment: Please take your source code out of the image and insert it into the question as text.

Comment: @BrokenBinary oke

Comment: @BrokenBinary there you go

Comment: If you use `command=lambda : clickhere` you have to write `command=lambda : clickhere()`. Note the **`()`**! As you don't pass any parameter, you should use `command=clickhere`, without `lambda:`

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
from tkinter import *
root= Tk()
topup = StringVar()

TextBox_1 = Entry(root, width=20, textvariable=topup)
TextBox_1.grid(column = 1, row = 3)

def clickhere():
    f = open("TOPUP.txt", "r+")
    w = f.readline()
    t=int(w)+ int(topup.get())
    f.seek(0)
    f.truncate()
    f.write(str(t))
    f.close()
button_ = Button(root, text='Top up!', command=clickhere, width=17)

button_.grid(column=2, row=3)
```